# Adobe Flex ToggleSwitch alternative for desktop applications

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am looking for a ToggleSwitch alternative for a Adobe Flex desktop application that I am working on.

For ref:- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS7dd5c1363434bb70-30e3f7e3131b54bf0ee-8000.html

This functionality has been released for Mobile development, but I couldn't find an alternative to build/have such functionality for desktop environments.
The closest alternative is ToggleButton (which is same functionally, but it doesn't look anywhere similar to the ToggleSwitch.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wy can't you use the Mobile ToggleSwitch in a desktop app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:-

http://yonaskolb.com/blog/2012/1/18/flex-toggle-switch-spark-skin.html

Adobe still hasn't released this for desktop themes, so one would need to use the mobile component (by including them in the build path)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the ToggleSwitch for non-air apps but you could simulate it pretty easily by doing an owner draw with the two button-states as images: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/02/11/styling-specific-states-in-an-fxtogglebutton-control-in-flex-gumbo/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I guess your pointer to using 2 images for different states will do the job.. it just doesn't show the transition from one state to the other (slider moving from on to off or vice versa). I am making a desktop application in adobe air.

Comment: Im sure there are ways to smooth out the transition. The fx:style can accomplish quite a lot.